# Nodejs cluster unable to kill worker running infinite loop

Tags: node.js

It is possible to kill a cluster worker that is running an infinite loop?  I've tried, but unable to kill the worker.  I guess the kill command cannot get onto the worker's js event loop.  Any ideas on how else I can do this?  When the master receives a "start" message, I want it to fork a worker.  When the master receives a "stop" message, I want it to kill the worker.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const process = require('process');
const { nrpin, nrpout } = require("./helpers/PubSub");
const chalk = require('chalk');

//https://leanpub.com/thenodejsclustermodule/read
//https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2232358

const arrWorkers = [];

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    masterProcess();
} else {
    childProcess();  
}

function masterProcess() {
    
    console.log(chalk.blueBright(`Master ${process.pid} is running`));

    nrpin.on("start", async (bot) => {
        console.log("Start:", bot._id);
        if (arrWorkers.length == numCPUs){
            console.log(chalk.yellowBright("No CPUs available to create worker!"));
        }
        const worker = cluster.fork();
        arrWorkers.push({
            workerId: worker.id,
            botId: bot._id
        })
    })

    nrpin.on("stop", async (bot) => {
        console.log("Stop:", bot._id);
        const worker = arrWorkers.find(x => x.botId == bot._id);
        if (worker){
            console.log("killing worker:", worker.workerId);
            cluster.workers[worker.workerId].kill();
        }
    })

    // Be notified when workers die
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        if (worker.isDead()) {
            console.info(`${chalk.redBright('worker dead pid')}: ${worker.process.pid}`);
        }
    });

}

function childProcess() {
    console.log(chalk.green(`Worker ${process.pid} started...`));
    while(true){
        console.log(Date.now());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I solved this using process.kill

```
let process_id = cluster.workers[worker.workerId].process.pid;
process.kill(process_id);
```